# add different images in firebase Storage

Tags: swift, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I want to add different images in my firebase Storage, but the problem is that, my code only adds one in a Storage file, is it possible to add more than one?

```swift
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
let db = Firestore.firestore()

guard let imageData = self.countryImage.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4) else {
    return
}
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://covidregulationsapp.appspot.com/")
let storageProfileRef = storageRef.child("savedImage").child(userID)
let metadata = StorageMetadata()
metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
storageProfileRef.putData(imageData,metadata: metadata)
{ (storageMetadata, error) in
    if error != nil {
    print("error")
    }
    storageProfileRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url,error) in
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users/\(userID)/saved")
            .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Couldnt update : \(err)")
                } else {
                    db.collection("users/\(userID)/saved").addDocument(data: [
                        "country":self.countryTitle.text!,
                        "code":self.info,
                        "city":self.airport.text!,
                        "countryImage": url?.absoluteString                        
                    ])
                }
            }
    })
}
```

[image: firebaseStorage]

as you can see in the picture above, there is only one image in my `savedImage` Storage, it changes URL If I try to add different image, my end result is to add several images in the `savedImage` Storage

Comment: As far as I understood your ```storageProfileRef``` is unique for all the images. So every time an image is uploaded it replaces the previous one (unless the user id is changed).  Try using ```storageProfileRef.child("some_unique_id").putData(......)``` 
\n for unique_id use image_name or``` Uuid().v4()```

Answer (score 0):

You upload each image to this reference:

```
let storageProfileRef = storageRef.child("savedImage").child(userID)
```

So when you upload a second image, you end up overwriting the first one from that same user.

If you want to upload multiple images for a user, a common approach is to use the user ID as the "directory" name, and then generate a unique image name under there.

Something like this:

```
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
let storageProfileRef = storageRef.child("savedImage").child(userID).child(uuid)
```